# Loading and using DLLs

Tags: windows, variables, dll, loading

Correct me if I am wrong, trying to get some newbie doubts straight.

As far as I know, DLLs are system registered resources which get loaded into RAM when a process calls them. When this happens the called DLL gets referenced up, and it will stay loaded in RAM until this reference goes back to zero. So if a second program calls the same DLL (which is already in RAM), this DLL will be with reference of 2, and will only get unloaded when both programs close it.

Therefore, the DLL resources are shared between both processes right? So, lets say I have a DLL function called `void setA(int A)` and another `int getA()`. Lets say A was initialized with the value of 0. If I set A to 5 in the first process which opened the DLL, and then call `getA()` from the second process, will it give me the value 5?

What if I load the library, set A to 5 and unload the library. Then I load the library again and call `getA()`, it will return me 0 correct?
Is there a way to change a variable within a DLL permanently, so that even after unloading the value remains on the next load?

Comment: Code is shared.  Not data.  If data sharing across processes is required then it is up to you to declare a shared section in the DLL.  #pragma section in the MSVC++ compiler with the *shared* attribute.  Not otherwise fundamentally different from a memory mapped file.

Comment: So if I wanted to only share one struct, which gets processed overall the code. Would it be sufficient to declare the struct in a #pragma shared section?
And is it possible to change variables permanently within a DLL?

Comment: You are almost certainly heading the wrong way.  If you need data values to "remain" while a DLL is unloaded then you need a file.

Comment: Thanks Hans, thats what I thought. Two processes will use the DLL, and there is data which both of them acess and share. A way I thought was to save the configurations in a file and load it everytime the library loads, but was hoping for a simpler and quicker solution.